# Backbone js distant storage sync error restful

Tags: php, javascript, rest, backbone.js

I try to run basic CRUD operations with backbone js and PHP REFTful service.

Then my web service works fine but i have trouble with backbone sync when i want delete there is no JSON send to my web service but with add,update i have that JSON.

So i cant't delete with my web service, maybe i have the bad method to do that.

That is the code :

app.js

```
$(function(){

    //MODELES
    window.Article = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults : {
            id : null,
            titre : null,
            contenu : null,
            image : null
        },
        initialize : function Doc() {
            console.log('Article Constructor');

            this.url = "index.php/article/article/id/"+this.id,

            this.bind("error", function(model, error){
                console.log( error );
            });
        },
        validate: function( attributes ){
            if( attributes.titre === '') {
                return "Titre ne peut pas être vide ";
            }
        }
    });

    //COLLECTIONS
    window.Articles = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model : Article,
        url : "index.php/article",
        initialize : function() {
            console.log('Articles collection Constructor');
        }
    });
});
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Main Page</title>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();  ?>js/vendor/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();  ?>js/vendor/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();  ?>js/vendor/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();  ?>js/app.js"></script>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm doing my test in the chromium console.

```
listArticles = new Articles();
unArticle = new Article();
unArticle.set('titre','Le titre');
listArticles.add(unArticle);
unArticle.save(); //THAT WORKS
unArticle.destroy(); //DONT WORKS (SEND THE REQUEST BUT WITHOUT THE JSON, WITHOUT GET ID)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : [Backbonejs with Restful servcies](http://duganchen.ca/backbone-js-and-restful-web-services/)

it is a good example about Backbonejs and restful services.